# Difference between idol worship and Shrine worship

Tags: avodah-zarah

What is the Jewish doctrinal  **difference** between an Idol housed in a temple and a grave housed in **Mausoleum** or Shrine  with all or some of the following activities carried out by the visitors in both the cases towards the Object (Grave or Idol):

The Visitors:

1. believe in one God of Moses and consider the Object or the dedicated person to be near to God.
2. revere the Object with clothes, flowers, incense, golden artifacts and enclosures to glorify it.
3. read some mantras from their religious scriptures in the vicinity of the Object.

**Update:**

Just clarified my question, stating further assumptions:

4. Visitors believe that the object does NOT have power of its own in the same way a Hindu idol worshiper does not believe the idol to have any intrinsic power and is mere a center of focus

Visitors occasionally would also invoke the Object not necessarily at that place.

This question is based on my assumptions that Jewish texts allow constructions of buildings and shrines \ Tombs over the graves of pious people, if it does not allow then question would be re-framed.

Comment: What does "invoke the Object" even mean?

Comment: e.g saying "O Moses help us"

Comment: Moses is not an object, Moses was a person. It is strictly forbidden to pray to another person (and certainly forbidden to pray to an object). It is however permitted to ask the person (deceased or alive) to pray to God on ones behalf. I don't know if this answers your question.

Comment: So it would be forbidden to say "O Moses help us", but permitted to say "O Moses, please pray to God that he would help us". (But in general Jews do not do that, Jews direct prayer directly to God, no intermediary is necessary or desired.)

Comment: So Can moses hear you as he is dead?

Comment: The deceased is still interested in what happens to his children and/or students and is in some way aware of this world. This would be a good article for you to read: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/562222/jewish/Is-it-okay-to-ask-a-deceased-tzaddik-to-pray-on-my-behalf.htm (A Tzaddik is a righteous person.)

Comment: This article confuses the matter more as it mentions that torah forbids invoking the dead, can you also update you r answer where torah prohibits invoking

Comment: The article very clearly distinguishes the two and explains the difference - did you read the whole thing?

Comment: Islamic tradition says that The first time in human history that people commited the sin of idol-worship was around the time of Prophet Noah (عليه السلام). A very pious man passed away. Shaytan(satan) whispered in the ears of the townspeople: he urged them never to forget this pious man lest the townspeople abandon his example and be lost to sin. Once Shaytan had convinced them of the necessity to revere the memory of this pious dead man, he then then convinced them to erect a shrine over the grave of this man.

Comment: Eventually, the people started praying in the shrine, and soon thereafter Shaytan convinced them to pray to the deceased man.

It was in this step by step fashion that Shaytan was able to misguide people into Shirk(shituff). He convinced them that they were doing a good thing by respecting a pious man, and he allowed them to add one Bidah (evil innovation) after another, infusing polythiestic practise in their belief

Comment: And hence the Islamic traditions compare Shrines over graves with idolatry yet some of the Indian muslims living in polytheistic society too have fallen in this trap

Comment: The Rambam describes how people came to worship the sun, see: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/912359/jewish/Chapter-One.htm Anyway, in Judaism the shrine is just a building, and the prayers are never TO the deceased, but rather that the deceased should join with the person together in prayer to God.

Comment: How can deceased join in

Answer (score 2):

Your question assumes that Jews consider the *object* to be near God.

They don't. The soul of the buried person might be, or the object might be near a holy site, but the object itself has no power. (And the site is holy not for itself, but for the activities that took place there.)

There is a difference between respecting an object (for example Tefillin - Phylacteries) and considering that object to be "near God" as it were.

An object might be used in the worship of God, but the object itself is never the focus - God is.

God said to use an object in a certain way (for example a Lulav - palm frond), so we do. But that's as far as it goes, the object is important only because God said for us to use it in a certain way, the object for itself has no significance.

Sometimes an object has the name of God written in it (like a Mezuza, scroll) that is placed on the door. In that case it's the name of God that makes the object holy, not the object itself.